# In which part Im doing a mistake which results in overflow?

Tags: arrays, overflow

`I have print the numbers of words in letter in a sentence in a array
for Example:
hello ALL Im  jabish
the output is
5 3 2 6

but  getting

```
         5 3 2 12381917   ,some overflow in last word,
```

I uploaded my code as image As it not getting indented properly Sorry for that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohdAc.png)

So this is my input,
-> hello ALL Im jabish
the output is
5 3 2 6

but Im getting

```
         5 3 2 12381917 `
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a minor issue with the code. When you are trying to calculate the last element it was setting with the overflow in the last count because when the 2nd loop exits you need to set the last word count in array like `a[d]=count1`.

Here's the complete code:

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);
    
    int g=strlen(str);
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<g; i++) {
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    int a[count];
    int count1=0;
    int d=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<g; i++) {
        if(str[i] != ' '){
            count1++;
        }
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            if(count1 < 100){
                a[d] = count1;
            }
            count1=0;
            d++;
        }
    }
    a[d]=count1;
    int c= sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```